# Generics, Property Call

Tags: c#, generics

Not sure if this can be done or not, but any help would be great.

I have created many POCO's, which have a property called Create that is a mapper function inside my POCO:

```
public class ReturnClass1 : IReturnClass1 
{
    protected IReturnClass1 _returnClass;
    public Create(IReturnClass1  retn)
    {
        var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, record.FieldCount).ToDictionary(record.GetName, i => i);
        return new ReturnClass1
        {
            column1= columns.ContainsKey("column1") && !record.IsDBNull(columns["column1"]) ? (DateTime?) record["column1"] : null,
            column2 = columns.ContainsKey("column2") && !record.IsDBNull(columns["column2"]) ? (DateTime?) record["column2"] : null
        }
    }
}
```

I have created a generic class that can return List.

```
public class ExecSqlServer
{
    public List<T> GetCollection<T>(StoredProcedureVariables args, int timeout = -1) where T: new()
    {
        var sqlDao = new DaoSqlServer();
        var sqlCmd = sqlDao.GetSprocCommand("stored_procedure_name");
        if (timeout >= 0) sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlDao.CreateParameter("variableString", args.VariableString));
        return (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(sqlDao.GetList(sqlCmd, new T().Create).ToList(), typeof(T));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is I need to invoke that Create, but can't because T does not contain the definition.

How can I get the definition?

Comment: Is your `Create` method on an interface and if not can it be?

Comment: You type constraint doesn't tell the method what `T` is supposed to be, perhaps you meant `where T : IReturnClass1, new()`?

Comment: `Create` isn't valid code... it must have a return value. It is not a property, but a method.

Comment: It currently is not, I could place it in one.

Comment: As @RonBeyer mentioned Create is not valid. And a POCO is not a place to implement this logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You type constraint on the `GetCollection` method doesn't specify what `T` is supposed to be so the compiler has no way to know about the `Create` method.

Because right now you could call the method with just about any type, for example `GetCollection<SomeOtherClass>()...` and that class doesn't contain `Create`.

Assuming the `Create` method is on the interface, most likely you meant:

```
public List<T> GetCollection<T>(StoredProcedureVariables args, int timeout = -1) 
    where T: IReturnClass1, new()
{
    var sqlDao = new DaoSqlServer();
    var sqlCmd = sqlDao.GetSprocCommand("stored_procedure_name");
    if (timeout >= 0) sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = timeout;
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlDao.CreateParameter("variableString", args.VariableString));
    return (List<T>)Convert.ChangeType(sqlDao.GetList(sqlCmd, new T().Create).ToList(), typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: `Create` takes a parameter in the OP's code (even if the code is invalid). I'm not sure how the OP determines what value to pass into that parameter.

Comment: @RonBeyer That's a different problem, but outside of the scope of the question asked

Answer (score 0):

You should add another constraint to your generic method:

```
public List<T> GetCollection<T>(StoredProcedureVariables args, int timeout = -1) where T: IReturnClass1, new()
```